# I am not able to use node-bourbon in the project

Tags: css, node.js, sass, angular, bourbon

I try to use npm module for scss files. Node-bourbon.

I get the following error:

```
  with: function() {
var paths  = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
return [].concat.apply([bourbon.includePaths], paths);
}
};

  Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var path =   require("
  in C:\Users\gwk736\GitLab\Inform\node_modules\node-bourbon\index.js (line   1, column 1)
@ ./src/app/header/header.component.ts 20:21-55
```

My scss first line:

```
@import "~node-bourbon";
```

My component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
selector: 'header',
template: require('./header.component.html'),
styles: [ require('./header.component.scss') ]
})
export class HeaderComponent {
headerTitle: string = 'title';
}
```

Comment: I have substantially the same problem.

Comment: Instead of massively marking answers as not useful you could do something useful and provide us with more information, so we can find out where **you** messed up help you. Now it starts to seem like you are simply trolling

Comment: @adam nowak
What kind of project are you running?  node.js with express or webpack?

Comment: Turns out there is an issue with node-sass version 7. I have posted two possible workarounds here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51502840/2212881