# Angular 2 Node Bourbon Error

Tags: angular, node-modules, bourbon, node-sass

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?
{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-
loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-
loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":
[]}!./src/styles.scss
Module build failed: 
var path = require('path');
^
  Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var path 
  = require("
     in 
  /home/dada/AngularProjects/playground2/node_modules/bourbon/index.js 
(line 1, column 1)
```

Hello... I'm trying to use bourbon in my Angular 2 project but when I install the package and try to import bourbon in my sass files I get the following errors? any ideas?!

Answer (score 4):

I came across this same issue when I had a node module that was referencing Burbon through an import statement.  It turns out that version 7 of sass-loader has a feature where it doesn’t select the sass file over the same named JavaScript file.

Link to the issues:

- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/556
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10535

There are two different work arounds to this issue. 
First you can add extension to your import statements, though I haven’t tested this approach personally.

```
@import ‘./cool-sass-file’ becomes @import ‘./cool-sass-file.scss’
```

The second route, which I verified was to roll back sass-loader to version 6.0.7

```
npm install sass-loader@6.0.7
```

Related question
 [I am not able to use node-bourbon in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914448/i-am-not-able-to-use-node-bourbon-in-the-project)